# Colon ":" symbol in Customer name cause error [QBO v3]

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Our clients want so their Customers have colons ":" in the company name (e.g. Rob:Barnett:Company'). Syncing such customer to QBO v3 cause the error

```
    com.intuit.ipp.exception.FMSException: ERROR CODE:2040, ERROR MESSAGE:Invalid String. The String may contain unsupported or illegal chars, ERROR DETAIL:Element contains invalid characters. Rob:Barnett:Company
```

That is probably because QBO v3 entities are being split with colons when the hierarchy is used (Parent:Customer:Job). So, is there a way for our guys to have colons in the company name, or this is impossible?

BTW, QBO web-face say that a field is invalid when trying to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QuickBooks uses colons as a special character to delineate parent/child heirarchies.

Thus, you can *not* have colons in customer names.